# Alternative hypotheses to Hebb's rule

Tags: neuroscience, learning, theoretical-neuroscience

I was reading on wikipedia that there are [exceptions to the hebbian rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hebbian_theory#Exceptions), and I was curious about the possibilities of other hypotheses of how learning occur in the brain. So I would like to know:

> are there alternative (or complementary) hypotheses to the hebbian rule?